# Pycharm Community Edition 4.5 - importing packages/modules

Tags: python, import, module, pycharm, python-3.4

I try to import a module in PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.
The module is in an separate folder (package) with subfolders...

Maybe this is a simple question for many programmers here, but how do I import the module into my project in order to use a Class, defined in the module.

To be a bit more specific:

(1) I have a package 'pythonds' which is a folder with several subfolders containing modules

(2) The path to pythonds is:

```
    E:\Tutorials\Python Tutorials\Bioinformatics_Algorithms/pythonds
```

(3) Among several subfolders there is the folder 'graphs' which contains the module 'adjGraph.py'

```
    E:\Tutorials\Python Tutorials\Bioinformatics_Algorithms\pythonds\graphs\adjGraph.py
```

(4) The module adjGraph.py contains a class I would like to import:

```
    I would like to import the class 'Graph' which is defined in the module adjGraph.py
```

Thank you very much in advance,

Best,
Werner

Comment: did you add the graphs subdirectory as a Python package, or just as a folder ?

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer that best solves your problem. Once you have 15 rep you can also upvote useful answers. Do so, it shows appreciation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
from graphs.adjGraph import Graph
```

Comment: Did it work ? It's possible that you have not set  up graphs as a python package, this can be fixed easily.  If you try my code and you get the error `ImportError: No module named graphs.adjGraph` you'll need to add an empty file to the graphs folder named "__init__.py", not that those are two underscores to either side of the word init.  That file turns the folder in to a python package, rather than just a folder.. If it does work, on the other hand, please upvote my answer and accept it with the check mark.

Comment: Thank you very much to OYRM for the quick response. 

This suggestion worked. 

One more question ---
What is the best way (most elegant / most professional way) in PyCharm to add a path for packages/modules. 

In my case I went to: Settings - Project Structure -  Add Content Root and added: E:\Tutorials\Python Tutorials\Bioinformatics_Algorithms\pythonds

Comment: I'd really need to know more about your file system structure to answer with my own preferences. That being said. your solution, of editing the PYTHONPATH using Pycharms project settings is very good. 

The goal that I work toward is that if I share the project, I want my co-workers to be able to use it without editing their paths a great deal.  Learn to use one of the VCS tools by reading the Pycharms help topic, Version Control with PyCharm so that you get used to importing and exporting projects.

Comment: @Honigdachs  If this solution worked for you,  please accept the answer. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)